# File Uploads with Webclient Class

Tags: c#, php, file-upload

This is the code for the form:

```
   form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
   input type="file" name="myFile" br
   input type="submit" value="Upload"
   /form
```

This is the server side php script:

```
if (!empty($_FILES["myFile"])) {
$myFile = $_FILES["myFile"];

if ($myFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    echo "<p>An error occurred.</p>";
    exit;
}

// ensure a safe filename
$name = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9._-]/i", "_", $myFile["name"]);

// don't overwrite an existing file
$i = 0;
$parts = pathinfo($name);
while (file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $name)) {
    $i++;
    $name = $parts["filename"] . "-" . $i . "." . $parts["extension"];
}

// preserve file from temporary directory
$success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"],
    UPLOAD_DIR . $name);
if (!$success) { 
    echo "<p>Unable to save file.</p>";
    exit;
}

// set proper permissions on the new file
chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 0644);
}
```

Stole the script from here
http://www.sitepoint.com/file-uploads-with-php/

And my c# code to upload the file:

```
private static WebClient _client = new WebClient(); 
private static Uri _address = new Uri("http://tildetictac.x10host.com/upload.php");

_logPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\log.txt"; //path to the log txt file  
try
    {
        byte[] ret = _client.UploadFile(_address, "POST", _logPath);
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    }
```

I had to butcher that html abit to make it display.  So the problem is that webclient when i try to upload the file doesn't show an exception, I've printed the return value and there is nothing and it seems to work fine, except the file isn't added to the directory.  If I use the form buttons myself, clicking browse and such, then it works fine.  The permissions should be fine, this all works by hand, and I don't get how I could have messed up the webclient code, it is only a line long and I've checked the url a million times, and the path is right 100%.

Comment: If the answer below is correct, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if you are using the HTML form to test if your server-side PHP is working.

Take a look at your html `<input type="file" name="myFile"/>`. When you POST, the data is saved in the `$_FILES` array with the name `myFile` as the key.

When you POST via C#'s `WebClient`, it chooses what the name should be. Try modifying your server-side PHP to check for `$_FILES["file"]` and it should work.

Comment: so when webclient posts it is using the name "file" and my server-side php is using "myFile"?

Comment: this worked bro.  Is there a way to specify what webclient calls to file, or is it always "file"? thanks

Comment: @hydrozoah I have not used the WebClient before in this way, but check this out. Using this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619105/post-values-not-received-in-php-when-submitted-with-net-webclient-class